# Writerows from python list - how can I remove brackets and apostrophes

Tags: python, list, data-cleaning

I have the below python code which goes through my csv file, removes all percentage signs (%), and rewrites the file back into a new csv file.

Before I run my code, the data looks as such:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | etc |

Now, it looks like this:

| ['Column 1' | 'Column 2' | 'Column 3' | 'Column 4' | 'etc'] |

**I don't want my data to include the brackets/apostrophes that are created by python's list functionality. I am afraid it will either, a) be included in my database when uploaded, or b) bomb out the import to the mySQL database. Any way around this?**

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import string

input_file = open('Data.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('NewData.csv', 'w')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file)
specials = '%'

for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line,specials,'')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`split(',')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) method in Python will return a list. Join them together using whatever separator you desire. If `new_line.split(',')` gives you something like `['Column1','Column2','Column3']` etc. then try

```
' | '.join(new_line.split(','))
```

This would give you something like `Column1 | Column2 | Column3`.

The syntax is a little different than most ppl are used to from other languages, but the join method in Python must be called on the separator, with the target list passed as the parameter.

Comment: I was trying to use the following syntax last night: ''.join(new_line.split(',')) However it put the letters of every character in it's own column again. Perhaps my drawing was not sufficient. The | (bracket) is not actually in my file, that was an attempt to make excel cells. -- so I'm not sure what ' | ' would do. Can someone elaborate?

Thanks. I'm very appreciative for the response!

Comment: @Dan Can you post a better example of what the actual file looks like? Give us an example of what a line of input looks like and exactly what output you would like to map it to, as well as the output you are currently getting.

Comment: I am currently at work, I will upload some data this evening. Thanks!